# RE-add DOM element in eventlistener callback after removing it

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
const addtasks = document.getElementById('task-add-btn').addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    const inputTask = document.createElement('input');
    inputTask.type = 'text';
    inputTask.placeholder = 'Add Task Description';
    console.log(inputTask);
    document.querySelector('.display-result-div').appendChild(inputTask);
    inputTask.addEventListener('change', (event)=>{
        fetch(`${window.origin}/add_task`, {
            method : "POST",
            credentials : 'include',
            body : JSON.stringify(event.target.value),
            cache : 'no-cache',
            headers : new Headers({
                "content-type" : 'application/json'
            })
        });
    });
    inputTask.remove();
    });
```

In above code I am creating an input tag on button-click and then removing that from DOM after getting its value.
I want following to happen every time I click my button:

1. Input tag is created and added to DOM, so that I can use its value
2. At the end input tag is removed from DOM

Above code doesn't add input tag to DOM after it gets removed first time.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just showing and hiding the field instead of adding and removing it?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're removing the `inputTask` element before it has a chance to be changed.

Before removing it though I would check to see if your `fetch` request returns a successful response, and also catch any errors:

```js
const addtasks = document.getElementById('task-add-btn').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const inputTask = document.createElement('input');
  inputTask.type = 'text';
  inputTask.placeholder = 'Add Task Description';
  
  document.querySelector('.display-result-div').appendChild(inputTask);
  
  inputTask.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    fetch(`${window.origin}/add_task`, {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify(event.target.value),
      cache: 'no-cache',
      headers: new Headers({
        "content-type": 'application/json'
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Success:', data);
      inputTask.remove();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      inputTask.remove();
      // you may wish to keep the input field here in this case
    });
  });
  
});
```

```html
<div class="display-result-div"></div>
<button id="task-add-btn">add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The added `input` is getting removed on `#task-add-btn` click itself. Ideally you would want to remove it once after the user entering some text and getting success response from backend.

So, moving the `inputTask.remove()` inside the success handler of `fetch` API would give you the expected behaviour.

```js
const addtasks = document.getElementById('task-add-btn').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const inputTask = document.createElement('input');
  inputTask.type = 'text';
  inputTask.placeholder = 'Add Task Description';
  console.log(inputTask);
  document.querySelector('.display-result-div').appendChild(inputTask);
  inputTask.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    console.log("change!!!");
    // Simulating the success response using `setTimeout` and removing the 
    // added input element after 1000ms
    setTimeout(() => {
      inputTask.remove();
    }, 1000);

   /* 
    // Ideally you would want to remove the newly added element once after getting the 
    // success response from the backend i.e., inside `.then` of the `fetch` API.
    fetch(`${window.origin}/add_task`, {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify(event.target.value),
      cache: 'no-cache',
      headers: new Headers({
        "content-type": 'application/json'
      })
    }).then(res => {
      //Remove the element after success response
      inputTask.remove();
    }).catch(err => {
      //Error handling
    })
   */
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="display-result-div"></div>

<button id="task-add-btn">Add Task</button>
```

For simplicity, here I have used `setTimeout` in order to remove the element after `1000ms` after the user entering some text in the newly added `input` element.

Comment: Got It.. Thanks a lot